# Uso de PI() en MySQL

Tags: mysql, function

quiero crear una función que me calcule el área de un círculo al pasarle el dato del radio. Hay algo que me chirría en el RETURN... ¿cómo puedo hacer para guardar la llamada a PI() en un float que pueda multiplicar por el cuadrado del radio?

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS area$$
CREATE FUNCTION area(r FLOAT)
    RETURNS FLOAT
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT PI())*r*r;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
SELECT area(2);
```

Comment: Tu versión es la más eficiente comparada con el proceso de asignarle PI a una variable, asignarle r^2 a otra y multiplicar esas dos. Se lee un poco mejor pero eso no es porque tu versión no sea legible. El nombre de las variables es significativo dado el contexto (la única mejora sería cambiar `r` por `radio`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código no funcionará en versiones anteriores a la `8`, porque en esas versiones existe una función que se llama [`area()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-polygon-property-functions.html#function_area), por tanto, en ese caso, debes cambiar el nombre de la función, por ejemplo:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getArea$$
CREATE FUNCTION getArea(r FLOAT)
    RETURNS FLOAT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT PI())*r*r;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select getArea(2);
```

| getArea(2) |
| --- |
| 12.566370964050293 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Si tu versión fuera la 8 o superior funcionaría, porque en esa versión la función pasa a llamarse [`ST_area()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-polygon-property-functions.html#function_st-area) y la antigua función `area()` fue sacada del núcleo de MySQL.

Veamos que funciona:

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS area$$
CREATE FUNCTION area(r FLOAT)
    RETURNS FLOAT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT PI())*r*r;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select area(2);
```

| area(2) |
| --- |
| 12.5664 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

No obstante, aunque estés en MySQL superior a 8, yo la seguiría llamando `getArea()`, por respeto a la antigua función y por ser una convención de nombre más adecuada.

Comment: Faltó responderle la parte de guardar `PI()` en una variable :P

Comment: Pensé que el fallo iba por ahí, pero no. El problema era el nombre de la función, de hecho el mensaje de error dice "Illegal parameter data type for peration 'st_area', así que solucionado"